# Angular - Toggle child with unlimited nesting

Tags: angular

I have an array that can have an unknown number of items and unlimited nesting. I need to be able to add a button to each parent that will toggle a display of the children, and each child can have a button to toggle its children. Also, each child will have a button that can toggle the parent off.

I'm having trouble getting the toggling to work. The way I have it now is based on the array's index, which for each set of children it starts back at 0, which can cause multiple items to open at the same time if they have the same index.

I have an example of my issue on Stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-menu-toggle?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

You can see the issue by clicking button "five", and then button "five.two". You can see it both opens "five.two" as well as "two" and "two.two" since they all have that same index.

So what I need is to be able to toggle an item, and it only affects its direct parent or child, not everything else at the same time.

Here is my array:

```
myArray = [
  {
    'title': 'one'
  },
  {
    'title': 'two',
    'children': [
      {
        'title': 'two.one'
      },
      {
        'title': 'two.two',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'two.two.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'two.two.two'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'two.three',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'two.three.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'two.three.two'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'three',
    'children': [
      {
        'title': 'three.one'
      },
      {
        'title': 'three.two',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'three.two.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'three.two.two'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'three.three',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'three.three.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'three.three.two'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'four'
  },
  {
    'title': 'five',
    'children': [
      {
        'title': 'five.one'
      },
      {
        'title': 'five.two'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'title': 'six',
    'children': [
      {
        'title': 'six.one'
      },
      {
        'title': 'six.two',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'six.two.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'six.two.two'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        'title': 'six.three',
        'children': [
          {
            'title': 'six.three.one'
          },
          {
            'title': 'six.three.two'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

And then I have a toggle variable in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
  this.toggle = this.myArray.map(i => false);
}
```

And finally, my HTML

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i = index">
    <button (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">{{item.title}}</button>
    <div *ngIf="item.children && toggle[i]">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: item.children, idx: i }"></ng-container>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #tree let-allItems let-idx="idx">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of allItems; let n = index">
      <button (click)="toggle[idx] = !toggle[idx]">X</button>
      <button (click)="toggle[n] = !toggle[n]">{{item.title}}</button>
      <div *ngIf="item.children && toggle[n]">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: item.children, idx: n }"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to create plain javascript object:

```
toggle: any = {};
```

and leverage combined index for state of specific item in your tree so it would look like:

[image]

As you can see above all indices are unique.

One thing you need to do is to pass correct index:

```html
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of myArray; let i = index">
    <button (click)="toggle[i] = !toggle[i]">{{item.title }} - {{i}}</button>
    <div *ngIf="item.children && toggle[i]">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: item.children, idx: i }">
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>

<ng-template #tree let-allItems let-idx="idx">
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of allItems; let n = index">
      <button (click)="toggle[idx] = !toggle[idx]">X - {{idx}}</button>
                              ^^^^
                           Parent index
      <button (click)="toggle[idx + '.' + n] = !toggle[idx + '.' + n]">{{item.title}} - {{ idx + '.' + n}}</button>
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                               Child index
      <div *ngIf="item.children && toggle[idx + '.' + n]">
        <ng-container 
          *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: item.children, idx: idx + '.' + n }"></ng-container>
                                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                                                           Child index becomes parent in next iteration
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Note how i produce new index through

```html
idx + '.' + n
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-menu-toggle-lz2mlh?file=src/app/app.component.html)**

Answer (score 1):

Make an item component which receives an item as an input. Now each item is only responsible for itself. The component template would be something like this:

```html
<p>
  <span>{{item.title}}</span>
  <button *ngIf="hasChildren" type="button" class="toggleBtn" (click)="toggleChildren()">Toggle Children</button>
  <button *ngIf="hasParent" type="button" class="toggleBtn" (click)="toggleParent()">Toggle Parent</button>
</p>


<ul *ngIf="areChildrenOpen">
  <li *ngFor="let child of item.children">
    <app-item [item]="child" [hasParent]="true" (toggleClicked)="toggleChildren()"></app-item>
  </li>
</ul>
```

This is much cleaner way of dealing with it.

**[A full Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yvh9mf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fitem%2Fitem.component.html)**

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a basic solution for recursive tree as following;

The trick is defining variable in parent template and use it for all child.If you click to parent then change showChilds variable to reverse then all childs will be hide or show.

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: myArray, idx: 1  , isChildOpen = false   }">
</ng-container>
    

    <ng-template #tree let-allItems let-idx="idx" let-showChilds="isChildOpen">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of allItems; let n = index">
          <button (click)="showChilds = !showChilds">X - {{idx}}</button>
                             
                               Parent index
          <button (click)="showChilds = !showChilds">{{item.title}} - {{ idx + '.' + n}}</button>
                                   Child index
          <div *ngIf="item.children && showChilds">
            <ng-container 
              *ngTemplateOutlet="tree; context: { $implicit: item.children, idx: idx + '.' + n, isChildOpen:showChilds  }"></ng-container>
                                                                                 
                                                               Child index becomes parent in next iteration
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ng-template>
```